# Using Fetch First with Case Expression

Tags: sql, db2

DB2 UDB v11.x.

Is it possible to use FETCH FIRST in an UPDATE query that uses CASE?  I sort of understand why it doesnt work but was wondering if there was a way.  for instance:

```
db2 "UPDATE mytable SET cstate = CASE WHEN cstate = 801 THEN cstate = 1 AND rstate = 1 WHEN cstate = 804 THEN cstate = 4 AND rstate = 4 END FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY"
```

This results in only one row being changed at a time.

Tried:

```
db2 "UPDATE mytable SET cstate = CASE WHEN cstate = (SELECT cstate FROM mytable WHERE cstate = 801 FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY) THEN cstate = 1 AND rstate = 1 WHEN cstate = (SELECT cstate FROM mytable WHERE cstate = 804 FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY) THEN cstate = 4 AND rstate = 4 END"
```

This gets:

```
SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES
INTO statement is more than one row
```

Any way to do this? Was hoping not to split it up and reiterating through the table twice (or having to do one update at a time).

Comment: What's the goal you try to achieve? Are you afraid, that a single `update` statement leads to log full condition?

Comment: Goals are 1) update while online so need to fetch in smaller batches to prevent locking 2) update quickly - having to run two different queries across a table of millions of rows would take long.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the simplest method

```
UPDATE
(   SELECT * FROM
    (   SELECT
            cstate
        ,   rstate
        ,   CASE WHEN cstate = 801 THEN 1 WHEN cstate = 804 THEN 4 ELSE cstate END new_cstate
        ,   CASE WHEN cstate = 801 THEN 1 WHEN cstate = 804 THEN 4 ELSE rstate END new_rstate
        FROM
            mytable
    )
    WHERE 
        cstate IS DISTINCT FROM new_cstate
    OR  rstate IS DISTINCT FROM new_rstate
    FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY
)
SET cstate = new_cstate
,   rstate = new_rstate
```

just keep running it until it updates no rows.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Its not working though...getting a :  SQL0407N  Assignment of a NULL value to a NOT NULL column "TBSPACEID=6,
TABLEID=5, COLNO=24" is not allowed.  SQLSTATE=23502
COLNO is the cstate column.  I tried modifying the query a bit but couldnt get it to work.  Also need to add the ability to modify the second column rstate...Im not clear on whether it is updated per the case statement or if it is only updated outside the subquery, which seems to defeat the purpose of the THEN in the case statement?

Comment: @NonasBuzines The expression `CASE WHEN cstate = 801 THEN cstate = 1 AND rstate = 1 WHEN ... END` returns Boolean value. I don't think, that it's really what you want - updating 2 int columns.

Comment: OK, I had not actually looked that closely at the CASE statement. I'll update my answer so it makes a bit more sense

Comment: I was not aware that Db2 supported `IS DISTINCT FROM`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use IN clause while dealing with subquery, you may have multiple values in the other table,

```
"UPDATE mytable SET cstate = CASE WHEN cstate in (SELECT cstate FROM mytable WHERE cstate = 801 FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY) THEN cstate = 1 AND rstate = 1 WHEN cstate in (SELECT cstate FROM mytable WHERE cstate = 804 FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY) THEN cstate = 4 AND rstate = 4 END"
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick response.  I tried the IN and received the following error:SQL0582N  A CASE expression in a VALUES clause, IN predicate, GROUP BY clause, or ORDER BY clause cannot include a quantified predicate, an IN predicate
using a fullselect, or an EXISTS predicate

Comment: I am setting two columns, including cstate depending on what cstate is set to. Id like to fetch x rows at a time to do this (in a loop) as I'll have potentially millions to do. I could just split this into two queries but wanted to avoid going through the table twice.

Comment: Query will not work in this way, you have to rewrite the query

Comment: Provide your sample data and desired result, having sub query without joining will not work

Answer (score 0):

You may try `positioned update` with commits after N such a updates.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_BATCH_COUNT INT DEFAULT 0;

  FOR V AS C1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
    SELECT 1 DUMMY FROM mytable FOR UPDATE OF cstate, rstate
  DO
    UPDATE mytable
    SET 
      cstate = ...
    , rstate = ...
    WHERE CURRENT OF C1;

    SET V_BATCH_COUNT = V_BATCH_COUNT + 1;
    IF V_BATCH_COUNT = 20000 THEN 
      COMMIT;
      SET V_BATCH_COUNT = 0;
    END IF;
  END FOR;
  IF V_BATCH_COUNT <> 0 THEN
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END
@
```

It works slowly, but can help you avoid excessive locking for a long time :)

Comment: ooow...cursors.  Haven't worked with cursors for a long time and that was in C code.  As you say, super slow. I am writing in shell script for this so it would actually be faster if I dumped the results either into a temp table or a file and then processed in small batches.  I was just looking for a silver bullet that I might be missing but thanks for the help.